# Disable all links in nested HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this snippet in my html code

```
<nav>        
    <ul class="test-list test-list-level-1">            
        <li class="test-page-1 test-heading-level-2">                
            <a class="test-link test-heading-1" href="#L1" title="t1">T1</a>            
        </li>            
        <li class="test-page-1 test-heading-level-2">                
            <a class="test-link test-heading-2" href="#L2" title="t2">T2</a>                
            <ul class="test-list-level-3">                    
                <li class="test-heading-level-3">                        
                    <a class="test-link test-heading-3" href="#L3" title="t3">T3</a>                    
                </li>                
            </ul>            
        </li>             
    </ul>    
</nav>
```

My goal is to set every href to "" to disable the link.

I tried

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$("a.test-link").removeAttr('href');
</script>
```

But nothing happened.

I set it to the footer and header.

EDIT: I solved it by surrounding it with

```
jQuery(function($){
                $("a.test-link").removeAttr('href');
            });
```

Comment: Working fine check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/01yc7jkz/)

Comment: it seems that it should work.  do you have any errors in the console? - also, do you have your `<script>` tag at the end of the HTML or at the beginning? (they way it is written, it should be at the end (before your closing `</html>` tag)

Comment: I solved it, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this:

```
$("a.test-link").removeAttribute("href")
```

Comment: "Did you try like this:" - OP already solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use this code in jquery.

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("a.test-link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```